# Memory transfer between work items and global memory in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I have some queries regarding how data transfer happens between work items and global memory. Let us consider the following highly inefficient memory bound kernel.

```
__kernel void reduceURatios(__global myreal *coef, __global myreal *row, myreal ratio)
{
    size_t gid = get_global_id(0);//line no 1

    myreal pCoef = coef[gid];//line no 2
    myreal pRow = row[gid];//line no 3

    pCoef = pCoef - (pRow * ratio);//line no 4
    coef[gid] = pCoef;//line no 5
}
```

1. Do all work items in a work group begin executing line no 1 at the
   same time?
2. Do all work items in a work group begin executing line no 2 at the
   same time?
3. Suppose different work items in a work group finish executing line
   no 4 at different times. Do the early finished ones wait so that,
   all work items transfer the data to global memory at the same time
   in line no 5?
4. Do all work items exit the compute unit simultaneously such that
   early finished work items have to wait until all work items have
   finished executing?
5. Suppose each kernel has to perform 2 reads from global memory. Is it
   better to execute these statements one after the other or is it
   better to execute some computation statements between the 2 read
   executions?
6. The above shown kernel is memory bound for GPU. Is there any way by
   which performance can be improved?
7. Are there any general guidelines to avoid memory bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find my answers below: *(thanks sharpneli for the good comment of AMD GPUs and warps)*

1. Normally YES. But depends on the hardware. You can't directly expect that behavior and design your algorithm on this "ordered execution". That's why `barriers` and `mem_fences` exists. For example, some GPU execute in order only a sub-set of the WG's WI. In CPU it is even possible that they run completely free of order.
2. Same as answer 1.
3. As in the answer 1, they will really unlikely finish at different times, so YES. However you have to bear in mind that this is a good feature, since 1 big write to memory is more efficient than a lot of small writes.
4. Typically YES (see answer 1 as well)
5. It is better to intercalate the reads with operations, but the compiler will already account for this and reorder the operation order to hide the latency of reading/writting effects. Of course the compiler will never move around code that can change the result value. Unless you disable manually the compiler optimizations this is a typical behavior of OpenCL compilers.
6. NO, it can't be improved in any way from the kernel point of view.
7. The general rule is, each memory cell of the input is used by more than one WI?

   - **NO (1 global->1 private)** *(this is the case of your kernel in the question)*
   - Then that memory is global->private, and there is no way to improve it, don't use local memory since it will be a waste of time.
   - **YES (1 global-> X private)**
   - Try to move the global memory lo local memory first, then read directly from local to private for each WI. Depending on the reuse amount (maybe only 2 WIs use the same global data) it may not even be worth if the computation amount is already high. You have to consider the tradeoff between extra memory usage and global access gain. For image procesing it is typically a good idea, for other types of processes not so much.

**NOTE:** The same process applies if you try to write to global memory. It is always better to operate in local memory by many WI before writing to global. But if each WI writes to an unique address in global, then write directly.

Comment: Actually the answer to 1 and 2 depends heavily. As an example AMD HW workgroup of 256 has 64 items executing one line, maybe even more and only then next 64 within that workgroup start executing. There is a good reason why one must use local memory fences within a work group.

Comment: Yes you are right, you can't actually predict that all the threads will run together. Since for example they can be further divided in small parallel works (ie: 64 WI together in 4 blocks to make a 256 WG). Thats why the fences and barriers exists. I will update my answer.